# Why do I have to use $value on a FirebaseObjectObservable

Tags: angular, ionic2, angularfire2

I have the following node in my Firebase DB:

```
users
-$user
--public
---avatarUrl: 'https://myurl'
```

I retrieve this url like this:

```
lastMessage$: Observable<any>;
  recipientAvatarUrl$: FirebaseObjectObservable<any>;

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public messageService: MessageService,
    public authService: AuthService,
    public userService: UserService
  ) {
    console.log('ChatPreviewComponent#constructor');
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.recipientAvatarUrl$ = this.userService.getUserAvatarUrl(this.chat.recipient, this.authService.getCurrenUserCompany());
  }
```

Function "getUserAvatarUrl" is as follows in my Service:

```
getUserAvatarUrl(uid: string, company: string): any {
    console.log('UserService#getUserAvatarUrl - Get user avatar url for ', uid);
    let path = `/${company}/users/${uid}/public/avatarUrl`;
    return this.af.database.object(path);
  }
```

And finally, here is my view where I render the image:

```
<ion-item (click)="openChat(shortChat.id)">
  <ion-avatar item-left>
    <img [src]="(recipientAvatarUrl$ | async)?.$value" />
  </ion-avatar>
</ion-item>
```

I don't understand why I have to use $value to get the value of the node. I though that the async pipe would unwrap the FirebaseObjectObservable according to the AngularFire2 documentation.

Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the node of FirebaseObjectObservable that you want to subscribe contains an object then fields can be accessed like in a JavaScript object.

```
<img [src]="(recipientAvatarUrl$ | async)?.name" />
```

The primitive values(number, string, or boolean) are stored under $value.

```
<img [src]="(recipientAvatarUrl$ | async)?.$value" />
```